# Programmatically measuring text length using GDI+ Graphics.MeasureString issue 

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing, gdi+

I have the following code that is working on my local machine (Win 7, .NET 4), but it doesn't seem to work on the server. I want to programmatically measuring text length

Could anyone please help with it?

```
private float GetTextSize(string text, float textSize)
{
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1))
    {
        bmp.SetResolution(96, 96);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) 
        {
            using (System.Drawing.Font font = new System.Drawing.Font(fontName, textSize))
            {
                return g.MeasureString(text, font).Width;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I will consider any better solution if available.

Update:

How to detect if a font type is available on the machine?

Update 2:

Why does my question get minus points? Could anyone please give it an up vote.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please define "not working"? Maybe the font doesn't exist?

Comment: @rudi_visser: it means it does not perform as expect. "What else?"© :)

Comment: That's great, but what does it actually do?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. How to detect if a font type is available on the machine? Will it cause exception if a font type is not available?

Comment: @rudi_visser it programmatically measurs text length based on a specifed text and the font size.

Comment: @Johann, sorry I thought you was the OP :D @Pingpong I know what the code's meant to do, but what is the result on the server?

Comment: @rudi_visser, thank you for your advice. There is no exception log on the server. I guess it returns zero for the default value of float type, which the calling method use its own default size. I was unable to debug on the server.

Comment: Maybe not actual debugging no, but you can try popping a MessageBox with the return value, or creating your own logfile and writing debug items to it. It doesn't have to be provided by VS or anything..

Comment: c.f., https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31088/any-automated-system-to-compute-the-linear-length-of-a-letters-in-a-word-or-ph/31094#31094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it will return different text length even for text that has the same number characters, e.g. 1234 is longer than abcd for some font type. My previous logic is to compare the number of characters for each text, and pass the longest text to the method, which is not correct based on that reason.

The solution is to call the method for each text, and text length returned from the method is reliable to compare.